# How to find who is using a (netapp)network folder?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, shared-folders

This is what i get when I want to rename a network folder:

[image]

How can I see who is in the folder so that I can ask them to close the window or ... When you have 400 people in a project, it's difficult to find it.

I have tried unlocker, Resource monitor, ShareMonitor, IObitUnlocker, System Tray Share Monitor, ProcessExplorer to find the USER. No luck! Any one who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

This is generally found under

```
Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Computer Management -> Shared folders
```

on the computer/server where the folders/files are.

There you can see under "Opened files" a list of every file opened, and by whom.

Comment: I dont see any folders under Shared Folder! All of the shared folders between users are on "\\netapp.." server

Comment: You have to do this (Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Computer Management -> Shared folders) in the server where the files are! Probably on this "\\netapp..." server (if it is a Windows server at least)

Comment: I don't see anything under "Opened files". I guess the admin has not enabled the sharing modus or whatever you call it!